# XMLSerialize Throws An Exception. Trying to serialize a list, but got an error

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize an IList Collection. But it fails to generate an XML document in code. The error I got is "there is a problem

```
System.InvalidOperationException
{"There was an error generating the XML document."}
```

Here is my code

```
IList<TwitterStatus> statuses = new List<TwitterStatus>();
//I am omitting the code where it fills the statues list

 XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TwitterStatus));

            StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
            xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, statuses);
            var xml = sww.ToString();
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? instead of passing in TwitterStuts as a type of, should I have passed in a list instead?

Please advise.

Many thanks

Comment: did you tried to pass a list? Add the TwitterStatus class code and we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will need to pass the exact type of object you want serialized

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TwitterStatus>));
```

Comment: let me try that and see